# How to get the resolution on godot spatial shader?

Tags: glsl, godot

```
shader_type spatial;
void fragment ()

{
    vec2 i_resolution = 1.0 / SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE ;

    ...
    //fragColor = ...; 
    COLOR = ...; 'Constants cannot be modified' And this is other problem on spatial shader
}
```

SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE don't work on spatial shader? how to get the resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed `SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE` does not exist in Spatial Shader (it exists in Canvas Shaders).

The equivalent of `SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE` for Spatial Shaders is `1.0/VIEWPORT_SIZE`. That is, `VIEWPORT_SIZE = 1.0/SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE`.

Since `1.0/SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE` is what you want, you can use `VIEWPORT_SIZE` directly. It gives you size in pixels of the viewport (where the shader is being drawn, be it the screen, a window, or a texture).

Furthermore, if you are going to do `FRAGCOORD.xy/VIEWPORT_SIZE`, you can use `SCREEN_UV` instead. That is `SCREEN_UV = FRAGCOORD.xy/VIEWPORT_SIZE`. As you would expect, `FRAGCOORD` is the fragment coordinates in pixels, while `SCREEN_UV` gives you normalized coordinates (0 to 1).

*By the way, if you don't want the material to depend on the position on screen, you may swap `SCREEN_UV` for `UV`.*

*By the way yes, I know `SCREEN_UV` says "screen" and not "viewport". Some naming can be confusing.*

---

In your spatial shader you don't write to `COLOR`, you write `ALBEDO` and `ALPHA` instead. Godot will notice if you write to `ALPHA` or not, and take that into account for deciding render order (so potentially transparent materials are rendered after opaque ones).

---

*Speaking of confusing naming…*

```
mat4 ModelToWorld  = WORLD_MATRIX;              // Common name: Model Matrix
mat4 WorldToModel  = inverse(WORLD_MATRIX);     // Common name: Inverse Model Matrix
mat4 WorldToCamera = INV_CAMERA_MATRIX;         // Common name: View Matrix
mat4 CameraToWorld = CAMERA_MATRIX;             // Common name: Inverse View Matrix
mat4 ModelToCamera = MODELVIEW_MATRIX;          // Common name: View Model Matrix
mat4 CameraToModel = inverse(MODELVIEW_MATRIX); // Common name: Inverse View Model Matrix
mat4 CameraToClip  = PROJECTION_MATRIX;          // Common name: Projection Matrix
mat4 ClipToCamera  = INV_PROJECTION_MATRIX;      // Common name: Inverse Projection Matrix
```

---

Please refer to [Spatial Shaders](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shading/shading_reference/spatial_shader.html), for the list of built-ins (including those mentioned above) and render modes.

Comment: thanks, godot it confuses me to translate the glgs to gdscript shader :/  I cling to c#